# Django: prefetch_related grants performance only for non paginated requests?

Tags: python, django, performance

For example, I have 1000 Users with lots of related objects that I use in template.

Is it right that this:

```
User.objects.all()[:10]
```

Will always perform better than this:

```
User.objects.all().prefetch_related('educations', 'places')[:10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will do an extra query to fetch the related objects for `educations` and `places`.

```
User.objects.all().prefetch_related('educations', 'places')[:10]
```

However it will only fetch the related objects for the sliced queryset `User.objects.all()[:10]`, so you don't have to worry that it will fetch the related objects the thousands of other users in your database.